# Как выполнить код после завершения загрузки ajax?

Tags: javascript

Код ниже не работает, т.е. ниже await ничего не выполняется

```
async function click(){
await ajax(this);
console.log(123);
}
function ajax(){
return new Promise(function(){...})
}
```

Comment: @AzizUmarov а как надо? Мне же надо дождаться загрузки аджакса, это я и делаю

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое хотели?

```js
async function click(){
  let result = await ajax();
  console.log(`ajax result is ${result}`);
}

function ajax( ) {
  return new Promise(
  function(resolve, reject)
  { 
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("doing something"); 
      resolve("ok");
    }, 2000);
    
  });
}


click();
```

Comment: так я то же самое сделал. ajax получает данные с сервера и сразу их вставляет в dom, ничего не возвращая

Comment: @Artyom что за ajax?  fetch или XmlHttp... или .ajax()?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest, возвращается готовая вёрстка

Comment: Приложите кода побольше и проблему?

Comment: async function click(){
await ajax(this);
console.log(123);
}
function ajax(){
return new Promise(function(){
/*
получаю id категроии и отправляю ей на сервер,
с врвера приходит готовая вёрстка и я её вставляю в нужный блок
*/
})
}

как тут вставить код я незнаю

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы работал `await`, промис должен когда-то завершиться, а судя по тому, что там коллбэк без параметров, этого не происходит никогда.
2. Чтобы что-то отработало, функцию надо где-то вызвать. Это про `click`.

Comment: должно быть так?
new Promise(function(res, rej){
...
res();
})
в res не обязательно что то прописывать?

Comment: @Artyom, для того, чтобы вывелось `123` можно не прописывать. А чтобы что-то заработало, надо бы прописать.